# All fragments show when back button is pressed in Android

Tags: android, fragment, back

I have fragments A, B, C, D, and E, I am using the show and hide implementation for switching between the fragments. So for example, if fragment A is being displayed I hide B, C, D, and E. Same thing if I click on B, then fragments, A, C, D, and E are hidden, with this method I am unable to get the back button presses to function the way I would want, so right now every time a user switches to a different fragment I add the fragment to the back stack. However the issue I am having is that when I press the back button, all of the previous fragments get displayed ALL at once, lol it looks crazy on the phone, but anyway, can anyone advise on how I can fix this issue?

Snippet of my Code:

```
public void onAccountSettingsSelected(){
        // Return if the fragment is the same
        if(mAccountSettingsFragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d("The World of Go ", "Account Settings fragment already is visible in container, returning");
            return;
        }else {
            secondFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mAccountSettingsFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Account Settings fragment already in container, re-showing the original Account Settings fragment");
                secondFragmentTransaction.show(mAccountSettingsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Account Settings fragment is not already in container, creating new Account Settings fragment");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                mAccountSettingsFragment.setArguments(args);
                secondFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, mAccountSettingsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            // Hide the User Favorites fragment
            if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mUserFavoritesFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Maps fragment
            if (mMapsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mMapsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Broadcast fragment
            if (mBroadcastFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mBroadcastFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Friends fragment
            if (mFriendsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mFriendsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Login fragment
            if (mLoginFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mLoginFragment);
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            secondFragmentTransaction.commit();
            mIsUserFavoritesOpen = false;
            mIsMapsOpen = false;
            mIsFriendsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void onUserFavoritesSelected(){
        // Return if the fragment is the same
        if(mUserFavoritesFragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d("The World of Go ", "User Favorites fragment already is visible in container, returning");
            return;
        }else {
            secondFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "User Favorites fragment already in container, re-showing the original User Favorites fragment");
                secondFragmentTransaction.show(mUserFavoritesFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "User Favorites fragment is not already in container, creating new User Favorites fragment");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                mUserFavoritesFragment.setArguments(args);
                secondFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, mUserFavoritesFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            // Hide the Maps fragment
            if (mMapsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mMapsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Account Settings fragment
            if (mAccountSettingsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mAccountSettingsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Broadcast fragment
            if (mBroadcastFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mBroadcastFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Friends fragment
            if (mFriendsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mFriendsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Login fragment
            if (mLoginFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mLoginFragment);
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            secondFragmentTransaction.commit();
            mIsUserFavoritesOpen = true;
            mIsMapsOpen = false;
            mIsFriendsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void onMapsSelected(){
        // Return if the fragment is the same
        if(mMapsFragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d("The World of Go ", "Maps fragment already is visible in container, returning");
            return;
        }else {
            secondFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mMapsFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Maps fragment already in container, re-showing the original maps fragment");
                secondFragmentTransaction.show(mMapsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Maps fragment is not already in container, creating new maps fragment");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                mMapsFragment.setArguments(args);
                secondFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, mMapsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            // Hide the User Favorites fragment
            if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mUserFavoritesFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Account settings fragment
            if (mAccountSettingsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mAccountSettingsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Broadcast fragment
            if (mBroadcastFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mBroadcastFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Friends fragment
            if (mFriendsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mFriendsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Login fragment
            if (mLoginFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mLoginFragment);
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            secondFragmentTransaction.commit();
            mIsUserFavoritesOpen = false;
            mIsMapsOpen = true;
            mIsFriendsOpen = false;
        }
    }

    public void onFriendSelected(){
        // Return if the fragment is the same
        if(mFriendsFragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d("The World of Go ", "Friends fragment already is visible in container, returning");
            return;
        }else {
            secondFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mFriendsFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Friends fragment already in container, re-showing the original Friends fragment");
                secondFragmentTransaction.show(mFriendsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Friends fragment is not already in container, creating new Friends fragment");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                mFriendsFragment.setArguments(args);
                secondFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, mFriendsFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mUserFavoritesFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Maps fragment
            if (mMapsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mMapsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Broadcast fragment
            if (mBroadcastFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mBroadcastFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Account Settings fragment
            if (mAccountSettingsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mAccountSettingsFragment);
            }
            // Hide the Login fragment
            if (mLoginFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mLoginFragment);
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            secondFragmentTransaction.commit();
            mIsUserFavoritesOpen = false;
            mIsMapsOpen = false;
            mIsFriendsOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public void onBroadcastSelected(){
        // Return if the fragment is the same
        if(mBroadcastFragment.isVisible()){
            Log.d("The World of Go ", "Broadcast fragment already is visible in container, returning");
            return;
        }else {
            secondFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mBroadcastFragment.isAdded()) { // if the fragment is already in container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Broadcast fragment already in container, re-showing the original Broadcast fragment");
                secondFragmentTransaction.show(mBroadcastFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            } else { // fragment needs to be added to frame container
                Log.d("The World of Go ", "Broadcast fragment is not already in container, creating new Broadcast fragment");
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                mBroadcastFragment.setArguments(args);
                secondFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.detail_fragment_container, mBroadcastFragment);
                secondFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mUserFavoritesFragment);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mMapsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mMapsFragment);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mFriendsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mFriendsFragment);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mAccountSettingsFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mAccountSettingsFragment);
            }
            // Hide User Favorites fragment
            if (mLoginFragment.isAdded()) {
                secondFragmentTransaction.hide(mLoginFragment);
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            secondFragmentTransaction.commit();
            mIsUserFavoritesOpen = false;
            mIsMapsOpen = false;
            mIsFriendsOpen = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change youe line: "if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isAdded())"
to ""if (mUserFavoritesFragment.isVisible())"